# Change the style of html tag in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to change the style of the h1 tag using style attributes in React, but only for color attributes that work.

```
<h3 style={{color: "white", font-family:"opensans-bold"}}> Hello World! </h3>
```

This is not working, and I'm getting this
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c03zi.jpg)

Comment: `font-family` is not a valid object key. You need to use `fontFamily` instead.

Comment: The error you are getting is unrelated to your style attribute. https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-jsx-expressions-must-have-one-parent-element

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `font-family` to `fontFamily`.
2. The `h1` tag should comes under an parent a tag like `div` or `<></>`
   I guess your code look like this( check the 'your code' link below).
   [Your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIcQG.png)

If yes, Please change your code something like this inside the return

```
<div>
  <h3 style={{color: "red", fontFamily:"opensans-bold"}}> Hello World! </h3>
</div>
```

or

```
<>
  <h3 style={{color: "red", fontFamily:"opensans-bold"}}> Hello World! </h3>
</>
```

If the error is gone but nothing is displayed in the web page, please change the color and check.
I'm attaching my code and output here please refer.

App.js

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3 style={{color: "red", fontFamily:"opensans-bold"}}> Hello World! </h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My output:
[Output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVCEV.png)

If you find this answer useful, please vote this answer.